# How to call setstream from dbcontext

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

I'm using entity framework 4.4 and using `DataServiceContext` to upload media (image file) to server file system along with media data(metadata). I'm using code first approach in entity framework. Here I set the property `HasStream` to the model for which media will stream. I was not able to upload media from client application. How to call `context.SetSaveStream();`

```
        List<MediaAttachmentDetail> trackedEntites = context.MediaAttachmentDetails.ToList();
        Stream fs = File.OpenRead(filePath);


        //trackedEntites.Add(media);
        context.MergeOption = System.Data.Services.Client.MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
        context.AttachTo("MediaAttachmentDetails", media);
        context.SetSaveStream(media, fs, true, "jpg", media.MediaAttachmentName);
        context.UpdateObject(media);
        //context.UpdateObject(media);
        var response = context.SaveChanges().FirstOrDefault();
        //context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: *I was not able to upload media* Why not? Errors, nothing happened, ...?

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The context is not currently tracking the entity.
  Source=Microsoft.Data.Services.Client

Comment: Edit your question please, giving the *full* error, not only *An error occurred...*.

Comment: error saying : The context is not currently tracking the entity.

Comment: Hi @GertArnold can you please provide steps to save entity to database along with media attachment using SetSaveStream() from the client application?

Thanks in advance,